# Copy a cookie from browser session

Tags: angular, session, cookies, browser

I have an application running on Jboss server, let's say 'App1'. After authentication, cookies are generated and I want the same cookies to be utilised by another application, let's say 'App2' which is running on the same instance of Jboss server. Basically I want to use the same cookies from browser to run 'App2' as standalone application.

I have tried to use the cookie generated from 'App1' and passing it through query param to 'App2'. This way I am able to run 'App2' only when 'App1' is up and running. This approach does not help me in running 'App2' as standalone application.

I am using this service from angular 
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service'

Answer (score 0):

Cookies by default are session cookies, which means they are cleared after browser shut down. you can make it last by setting a max-age, so it will be always effective before it expires.